# VBA SetForegroundWindow

Tags: excel, vba, setforegroundwindow

I'm trying to write code that periodically puts/makes sure a program is in front of all the others. To test this I have used Notepad.
This code only seems to work if I open a new program in front of Notepad - and not if I open a program; then start to execute my code; then put the other already open program in front of notepad. In this case notepad only blinks orange in the taskbar.
Can anybody help me with this?

```
Sub test()
    Dim vPID As Variant
    vPID = Shell("notepad.exe", vbMaximizedFocus)
    AppActivate vPID

    'Notepad opens, I put another program in front of it
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

    'I want Notepad back in front again:
    Dim HWND As Long
    Dim SetFocus As Long
    HWND = FindWindow("Notepad", vbNullString)
    SetFocus = SetForegroundWindow(HWND)

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

    'Close Notepad
    Call Shell("TaskKill /F /PID " & CStr(vPID), vbHide)
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have code behind `SetForegroundWindow`? (see [mcve]) Assuming you're referring to the API, have you looked at examples from other questions using [tag:getforegroundwindow]?

Comment: While I avoid the method(s) myself, you might want to look into AppActivate.